# Get call from swf file to android code

Tags: javascript, android, flash, android-webview

I need to get **call from swf file** **to** our **android**. I am playing swf file using webview. For that i search it out that ***fscommand(),getURL()*** method of flash will help me to get calls in **javascript**  but i'm not getting it. how to do the things.

Comment: Please let us know how it worked ounce you crack it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a internal webserver based on [Jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/). Then call any HTTP request to this internal webserver (hosted on localhost) from your SWF file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, I am still not getting. I will give some example for what i want to do. I have one swf file in that i have one button when i clicked on the button of flash android will handle that event and fires toast on the screen. Means we will get swf event in android program

Comment: i am facing the same issue did u get any workaround to this